# MVC4 IgnoreRoute with HttpHandler and LESS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes, less, httphandler

I'm launching a new MVC4 site and am having significant trouble, I believe with routes.

This all works locally in Cassini but not on my production WIN 2012 server.

It seems like similar questions have been answered time and again; I'm either missing the obvious or going down the wrong track.

The two issues I am seeing are my LESS CSS is not loading. Other css like bootstrap is loading fine. I thought it could be a problem with MVC trying to handle the js request for less but other js from the same Scripts folder is working fine. I've been trying various IgnoreRoutes all day to no avail. Currently:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("Content/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("Scripts/{*pathInfo}");
        RouteTable.Routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.css/{*pathInfo}");
        RouteTable.Routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.js/{*pathInfo}");            

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("ImageDisplay.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("elmah.axd");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("FeedFiles/{*pathInfo}");
...
```

Unsure if it is realted but I have an image handler, ImageDisplay.aspx.

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="ImageDisplay.aspx" type="BK9.PL.Utility.ImageHandler, BK9.PL" />
</httpHandlers>
```

This is also failing with a 404 but works fine locally.

What am I missing?

UPDATE ----------------------

Turns out the image handler was bad config for IIS 8 - I had it configed in the system.web section - moving it to system.webserver resloved that.

As I was starting to wonder, digging into routes was completely the wrong path. The less issue turned out to be a dotless compilation problem.

Here's a proper post-build compilation for dotless 1.3.1.0:

```
del "$(ProjectDir)Content\BK9.css"
"$(SolutionDir)packages\dotless.1.3.1.0\tool\dotless.compiler.exe" -m "$(ProjectDir)Content\BK9.less" "$(ProjectDir)Content\BK9.css"
```

That deletes the last css, and compiles a new minified version. Seemed like the line break after the delete command was needed.

Comment: Turns out the image handler was bad config for IIS - I had it configed in the system.web section - moving it to system.webserver resloved that. The less css piece remains a mystery.

Comment: As I was starting to wonder, digging into routes was completely the wrong path. The less issue turned out to be a compilation problem with less.